# Does Rust allow you define Ord or PartialOrd for your type and external types?

Tags: rust, comparison

Let's say I want to define my own type..

```rust
struct MyString(String);
```

Does Rust let me define the behavior when comparing the string against another type, such as an `Option<MyString>`? I want to write something like this,

```rust
impl std::cmp::PartialOrd<Option<MyString>> {
    fn partial_cmp(self, other: Option<MyString> ) {
    }
}
```

But [I'm getting](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=109465d89143d05246862e0f2e1578f4),

> error[E0116]: cannot define inherent `impl` for a type outside of the crate where the type is defined [...] impl for type defined outside of crate. [...] define and implement a trait or new type instead

This is confusing to me because `MyString` **is my type**. Is this a violation of coherence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> impl for a type outside of the crate where the type is defined

Is because I left off `for MyString` in `impl ... for MyString {}`. An easy syntax error to make that can be fixed by adding that,

```rust
impl std::cmp::PartialOrd<Option<MyString>> for MyString {
    fn partial_cmp(self, other: Option<MyString> ) {
`
```

Then I get the much more reasonable error

```
error[E0277]: can't compare `MyString` with `Option<MyString>`
   --> src/main.rs:6:6
    |
6   | impl std::cmp::PartialOrd<Option<MyString>> for MyString {
    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `MyString == Option<MyString>`
    |
    = help: the trait `PartialEq<Option<MyString>>` is not implemented for `MyString`
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect. You also need to implment `ParialEq` because `PartialCmp` requires it:

```
#![allow(unused)]

use std::cmp::Ordering;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct MyString(String);

impl std::cmp::PartialOrd<Option<MyString>> for MyString {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Option<MyString>) -> Option<Ordering> {
        match other {
            None => None,
            Some(s) => s.0.partial_cmp(&self.0),
        }
    }
}

impl std::cmp::PartialEq<Option<MyString>> for MyString {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Option<MyString>) -> bool {
        match other {
            Some(s) => s.eq(self),
            None => false,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = MyString("foo".to_string());
    println!("{:?}", a > None)
}
```